# Is this too hardcoded?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, error-handling

I am trying to handle errors in ReactJs however I think what I did is 'too hardcoded'. 
The error handling checks if the input is number, else throws the error. I want to show users a message and tell them what they did wrong.

By standard, the error thrown when the user inputs something else than a number is:

> while converting number to string, invalid number value 'd', should be a number matching (^-?[0-9.]+).

To give them an informative message, I did the following:

```
try {
      /// some code here
    } catch (err) {
      /* this.state.value refers to user's input*/
      if(err.message === ("while converting number to string, invalid number value '"+ this.state.value +"', should be a number matching (^-?[0-9.]+)."))
      {
        /// code which returns an informative message
      }
  };
```

Is the if statement appropriate for error handling or could it be improved? I will obviously run error handling for different aspects of the project and check for different circumstances however I find myself repeating the same things over and over.

Comment: Quite a bit, yes. Why don't you pass another error property, called `name`, and check against that?

Comment: Sometimes I will add a key to the error before throwing. For example you could do ```throw { invalidNumber: true }``` and then just check if ```err.invalidNumber```

Comment: @Bernardo Siqueira Do you mean to create an array of strings containing all errors and then check against it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was writing a comment to follow up, just ended up running out of space.

It really depends on how you want to structure your project, and it's still quite subjective.

What I didn't quite like about the approach you took is that you directly checked for the message you're sending out to the user in order to handle it, and that message might not always be the same.

I would prefer to handle it a bit more like this:

```
try {
  /// some code here
  if (something) {
    throw { name: 'INVALID_NUMBER_VALUE', message: "while converting number to string, invalid number value '"+ this.state.value +"', should be a number matching (^-?[0-9.]+)." }
  }
} catch (err) {
  /* this.state.value refers to user's input*/
  if (err.name === 'INVALID_NUMBER_VALUE') {
    /// do something with your message
  }
};
```

Now you can abstract this further still. Let's say you have predefined error types within your project, you can create an object mapping for your errors in another file, and import it:

```
export const errorNames = {
    invalidNumberValue: 'INVALID_NUMBER_VALUE',
    invalidName: 'INVALID_NAME',
    // so on and so forth
}
```

And in the original file:

```
import { errorNames } from './errorNames'

try {
  /// some code here
  if (something) {
    throw { name: errorNames.invalidNumberValue, message: "while converting number to string, invalid number value '"+ this.state.value +"', should be a number matching (^-?[0-9.]+)." }
  }
} catch (err) {
  /* this.state.value refers to user's input*/
  if (err.name === errorNames.invalidNumberValue) {
    /// do something with your message
  }
};
```

Still a lot of this comes down to preference, but I like to keep the error handling organized.

Comment: Thanks Bernardo! I agree with you on keeping the error handling organized. I am considering your approach